# Finding all occurences of a string within a cell array (itself part of a struc)

Tags: matlab

I have the following structure

```
dataDens = 

     dens: [1x172 double]
    level: {1x172 cell}
     raga: {1x172 cell}
```

within which dataDens.raga consists of (reducing the number of columns below for simplicity)

```
Columns 1 through 3
    'Multani'    'Tori'    'Tori'
```

I'd like to find the indices at which 'Tori' appears (that is, [2 3] for the example above). However, all of the commands I tried (below) either give an error, or return blank outputs. I think it's probably just a matter of adding/removing a curly bracket somewhere, or using some conversion; but I am at my wit's end, and hope someone can help clarify

```
indices = find(strcmp([dataDens.raga{:}], {'Tori'}))
indices = ismember('Tori', dataDens.raga)
[if,where] = ismember('Tori', dataDens.raga)
```

Comment: For `indices = find(strcmp([dataDens.raga{:}], {'Tori'}))`, [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) returns true or false, so that is why the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) command will not work. You could iterate with a `for` loop.

Comment: Just `indices = find(strcmp(dataDens.raga, {'Tori'}))` should work fine (look at the output of `[dataDens.raga{:}]` to see why). `indices = find(ismember(dataDens.raga, 'Tori')` also works. You are checking for membership in the wrong order...

Comment: @medicine_man `find` would then return the indices of the true values, which is what op wants here, right? So using `find` is not the issue here, what is being compared is wrong.

Comment: Correct, issue is not with `find` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had indeed to do with brackets. `[dataDens.raga{:}]` will result in concatenation of the character arrays, like so:

```
>> [dataDens.raga{:}]
ans =
    'MultaniToriTori'
```

Using `strcmp` to compare this to `'Tori'` will result in false, since there is no exact match. You can however compare the entire cell using `strcmp`, which will then return a boolean array, in which `find` can be used to obtain the indices of `true` entries:

```
indices = find(strcmp(data, {'Tori'}))
```

Alternatively, `ismember` would also work, but using `ismember('Tori', dataDens.raga)` you are checking whether `'Tori'` is in `dataDens.raga`, not the other way around. Changing this to

```
ismember(dataDens.raga, 'Tori')
```

would again give you a boolean array, and `find` will obtain the indices you are looking for.